# array.push didn't push object based on sequence while some object do action with await

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm trying to loop my object with `map`, inside the `map` I need to do action with **sequelize** so I use `async` and `Promise.all` to support `async`, but it give me result that the object sequence is not like the original sequence, the sequence start with data that doesn't do action with **sequelize**.

For example:

```
const data = await Student.findAll({
    limit: 2,
    where: {
        level: 'Primary 1'
    },
    order: [['id', 'ASC']]
}).then(async resultStudent => {
    // [{"id": 1, "name": "Alex", "gender": "Male", "level": "Primary 1"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Betty", "gender": "Female", "level": "Primary 1"}]

    let finalData = [];

        await Promise.all(
            resultStudent.map(async (e, index) => {

                let studentHobbies;
                if(e.gender == 'Male'){
                    studentHobbies = await Hobbies.findOne({
                        where: {
                            studentID: e.id
                        }
                    })
                }

                let obj = {
                    id: e.id,
                    hobby: studentHobbies ? studentHobbies.hobbyName : null
                };

                finalData.push(obj);
            })
        )
})
```

The code above give me result as:

```
[{
    "id": 2,
    "hobby": null
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "hobby": "Playing Guitar, and Basketball"
}]
```

While my expected result was:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "hobby": "Playing Guitar, and Basketball"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "hobby": null
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is *almost* correct. What you need to change is the following. Instead of initializing the `finalData` array outside of the `map`-loop and pushing to it inside the `map`-function you should use the array that the `map` function returns and return the data object at the end of the `map`-function.

Also, you can simplify your code-flow by taking advantage of the nature of `async/await` and remove the `then` callback.

This should provide you the data in the right order:

```
// Change: No need to use the then-callback, when you are using await here
const resultStudent = await Student.findAll({
  limit: 2,
  where: {
    level: 'Primary 1'
  },
  order: [
    ['id', 'ASC']
  ]
})

// Change: Rely on map to return the data in the same order as it was passed in
const finalData = await Promise.all(
  resultStudent.map(async (e, index) => {
    let studentHobbies;
    if (e.gender == 'Male') {
      studentHobbies = await Hobbies.findOne({
        where: {
          studentID: e.id
        }
      })
    }

    let obj = {
      id: e.id,
      hobby: studentHobbies ? studentHobbies.hobbyName : null
    };

    // Change: Return data from map function
    return obj;
  })
)

// finalResult will have the same array order as resultSudent here
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try using map with async callback to keep the order:

```
const data = await Student.findAll({
    limit: 2,
    where: {
        level: 'Primary 1'
    },
    order: [['id', 'ASC']]
}).then(resultStudent => Promise.all(
    resultStudent.map(async student => ({
        id: student.id,
        hobby: (student.gender === 'Male')
          ? await Hobbies.findOne({ where: { studentID: student.id } })
          : null
    })
)))
```

Edit: easier to read version

```
const data = await Student.findAll({ // array of ordered results from query
    limit: 2,
    where: {
        level: 'Primary 1'
    },
    order: [['id', 'ASC']]
}).then(results =>
    results.map(async ({ id, gender }) => ({ // array of promises that run asynchronously and resolve with formatted objects
        id,
        hobby: (gender === 'Male')
          ? await Hobbies.findOne({ where: { studentID: id } })
          : null
    }))
  ).then(Promise.all) // array of results of resolved promises, in same order. resolves when all have completed
```

Each of the three arrays is wrapped in a promise. `const data = await` extracts the final result from the end of the promise chain.

Comment: My bad. My example is not as hard as the real issue. So, when I tried your, I don't know how to re-write mine with this way. What is the different between yours `resultStudent.map(async student => ({//logic}))` and mine `resultStudent.map(async student => (//logic))`

Comment: Mine goes: 1) get student data array from query 2) return a promise (promise.all) that resolves when the array of promises passed to it are resolved (the promises passed to it are the student data array elements mapped to promises in order) 3) Promise.all takes an array of promises and returns an array of results, in the same order- even if they did not run in order. so returning the result of promise.all gives the results array you needed

Comment: Whereas the way you had it, you were using promise.all to run a bunch of promises at the same time, but not keep the output of promise.all which is array that preserves the order. The promises run at the same time and push to results obj whenever they complete. Since males require an extra query, they finish last, and are pushed last, that is why Betty is first.

Comment: I think your confusion was just that map won't wait for a promise (async functions return a promise) to complete for moving on to the next iteration. It will push all the promises synchronously, in order, but the promises will run asynchronously and resolve whenever they are ready.

Comment: a function like `x => ({ a:1, b2 })` just returns an object. instead of having to do `x => { return { a:1, b:2 } }`

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try this one?

```
const data = await Student.findAll({
  limit: 2,
  where: {
    level: 'Primary 1'
  },
  order: [['id', 'ASC']]
})

const finalData = await Promise.all(

  data.map( async (e, index) => {

    let studentHobbies;

    if(e.gender == 'Male'){
      studentHobbies = await Hobbies.findOne({
        where: {
          studentID: e.id
        }
      })
    }

    const obj = {
      id: e.id,
      hobby: studentHobbies ? studentHobbies.hobbyName : null
    };

    return Promise.resolve( obj )

  })
)
```

if it works I'll give further explanations

Comment: Thanks man! This is also work well for me. But why did you should use `Promise.resolve()`?

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, the map() function already returns an array.

Try to modify your code to set `finalData` like so:

```
finalData  = resultStudent.map(async (e, index) => {
```

and delete following line:

```
finalData.push(obj);
```

Important: the declaration `let finalData = [];` needs to remain 'as is'

Comment: All `async` functions return a promise so `finalData` will be an array of promises.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes both of you right, if tried and it work well, thankyou somuch!